# SQL: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error while trying to execute the below query:

> 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function'

```
select A.NUMBER,
       SUBSTRING(A.DESCRIPTION,
                 CHARINDEX(','+CAST(A.Description as VARCHAR(255)) + ',','from')+4, 
                 CHARINDEX(','+CAST(A.Description as VARCHAR(255))+ ',','to')- 1)
from  dbo.ACTIVITYM1 A
where A.DESCRIPTION like 'Reassignment from%'
```

Schema Details:

- Activitym1 : Table Name
- Description : Column
- Number : Column.

Kindly let me know, what is the cause of this error.

A.Description contains something like below

"Reassignment from PSM_Support to PPM_Support"
I am trying to get PSM_Support in 1 column and PPm_Support in another column.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're specifying a length that goes past the end of the string.

Comment: The 3rd argument to `SUBSTRING` is the length of the substring, not the ending position. So you probably need to subtract the starting position.

Comment: @Barmar - lengths *over* the length of the string are fine, `select SUBSTRING('abcd',2,8000)` returns `bcd`. It's more likely that the length has come out as negative and caused the error.

Comment: Check your arguments. [`CHARIDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186323.aspx) wants the text to search for first and the text to search within second. I highly doubt you'll find anything containing two commas (+ whatever description contains) inside the texts `from` or `to`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your `substring` broken out:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    A.DESCRIPTION,
    CHARINDEX(','+CAST(A.Description as VARCHAR(255))+',','from')+4, -- start
    CHARINDEX(','+CAST(A.Description as VARCHAR(255))+ ',','to')- 1  -- length
)
```

I would check on the third parameter (length) by putting it into its own column. It must be > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have understood the syntax of CHARINDEX incorrectly. You have to search 'from' or 'to' in Description but not Description in 'from' or 'to'. I hope you understood the issue here. Just reverse them and you will get it correct.